# Calling a MSSQL stored procedure in Java

Tags: java, stored-procedures

I have access to a stored procedure on a sql server which has one parameter and I can easily run it on the sql client as follow:

```
exec sp_name "2016/11/01"
```

Now I want to do the same thing in java.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("sp_name ?");
ps.setString(1, "2016/11/01");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

In `rs` I can see the columns' names, but zero row is returned. I think it is because of the stored procedure's parameter. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the type of the one parameter? Anyway I would suggest you use [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) instead. Also, the problem might be in the SP itself... PS: better use ISO formatting formatting for dates, use formats `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DD` in SQL Server calls.

Comment: Well I don't know the type because I don't  have access to the source of the SP.

Comment: Perhaps try with a `(java.sql.)date` parameter?

Comment: Yes. I already tried to convert the string to java.sql.date, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that worked eventually:

```
String date= "2016/11/01"
String queryString "exec sp_dmp_pub_status ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);         
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date parsed = format.parse(date);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
ps.setDate(1, sqlDate);        
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```